# Does Google provide a search API

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

Does Google offer an API to perform web search? From my research, I could understand that Google Custom Search API can be used to perform search within our website. But that's not what I need. I would like to search the internet and get results back. That is, the Google alternative for Bing Search API.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that for not so popular sites, even if they have been around for years, Google will ever show only about 4% of their pages.

In 2022, I tested five SEO experts sites and out of the 1566 pages listed in their `sitemap.xml` files, Google only listed 402, or 26%. None of them explained why all their pages weren't listed, which makes it seem that they either don't know or they are incompetent. Either way, use of their services is rather dubious if they promote Google but coverage of their sites is so woeful.

Up until August 2023, Bing would return several times more than Google, but now returns 100%, and without Google's 200 limit for the `site:` filter.

Bing returns all pages for those SEO sites now as well.

For more details, see [Google search is lying to you!](https://smallsite-design.com/art/a-google-search-is-lying-to-you/)

I expect a lot of downvotes, as I already had a lot of pushback from several people on another SO forum when I previously tried to highlight Google's egregious discriminatory practice. Perhaps too many tech people are too enamoured with Search Central tools that they blindly accept that Google has valid reasons for ignoring many if not most of their site's pages. That Bing can now list all pages highlights that Google's actions are unwarranted. Hopefully Google will now live up to their implied legal responsibility to list all valid pages.

I suggested to the Bing team that they should immediately launch a worldwide advertising campaign highlighting how Google is letting down all their users by their failure to list all valid pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google Custom Search does what you want.  It has multiple sub-products, including Site Search which is the one that is for your own site, but also CSE which is a general web search.  It is primarily intended for searching subsets of the web, but has a feature where you can flexibly and dynamically define those subsets.

https://www.google.com/cse/
https://www.google.ca/cse/docs/

There is an API for "custom search":
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

The service is pretty good, but rather expensive at $5 / 1000 queries once you pass the 100 queries/day free tier.

Comment: Google Custom Search cannot be configured to search the whole Internet. It's required to specify URL patterns in Search Control Panel (and pattern "*" is illegal).

Comment: 'Google Custom Search does what you want.' Except for a not-so-popular site, it will only list about 4%.